# deleting menu items remotely

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

consider the following code:

```
            mntmProfilesDelete.get(index).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JMenuItem eMntm = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
                    String text = eMntm.getText();
                    Component[] mns = mnDelete.getParent().getComponents();
                    for(Component mn : mns)
                    {
                        System.err.println((String)(((JMenu)mn).getText()));
                        if(mn instanceof JMenu && ((JMenu)mn).getText().toLowerCase().equals("open"))
                        {
                            System.err.println((String)(((JMenu)mn).getText()));
                            Component[] mntms = ((JMenu) mn).getComponents();
                            for(Component mntm : mntms)
                            {
                                System.err.println((String)(((JMenu)mn).getText())+"\n"+(String)(((JMenuItem)mntm).getText()));
                                if(mntm instanceof JMenuItem && ((JMenuItem)mntm).getText().toLowerCase().equals(text.toLowerCase()))
                                {
                                    System.err.println((String)(((JMenu)mn).getText())+"\n"+(String)(((JMenuItem)mntm).getText()));
                                    ((JMenu)mn).remove((JMenuItem)mntm);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mnDelete.remove(eMntm);
                }
            }
```

which I'm using to delete two menu items, like below:

```
(jmenu)father
    (jmenu)open
        (jmenuitem)item1
        (jmenuitem)item2
        etc
    (jmenu)delete
        (jmenuitem)item1
        (jmenuitem)item2
        etc
```

the action listener is attached to -item1- below -delete-

for some reason the -item1- below -open- doesn't get removed using the above code. I can't seem to understand why.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, every part of my code works as it should except:

```
Component[] mntms = ((JMenu) mn).getComponents();
```

which does not return any JMenuItems, it should be:

```
Component[] mntms = ((JMenu) mn).getMenuComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

`JMenu`'s `remove(Component c)` JavaDoc says: "*Removes the component `c` from this menu.*"

AFAIC interpret from looking at the last line of your code (my weekend mind refused to dig through the casting galore<sup>[1]</sup> ;-) and your explanation: your *this* menu `mnDelete` is */father/delete*. The item you're trying to remove (*/father/open/item1*) is not in *this* menu.

<sup>[1]</sup> Why the heck are you casting `public String getText()` to `(String)`?

Comment: the String cast is because of the weird eclipse error, somehow that shut it up. my problem is it never goes into For(mntm : mntms) loop, it doesn't even get to remove. also the last remove(emntm) works perfectly, removing item1 below delete menu

Answer (score 0):

So I would save off my menu that I want to modify so I can easily perform this change.  As opposed to trying to wind through the hierarchy.  This will make it much easier to read your code.  For example:

```
public SomeApp {

   JMenu openMenu;
   JMenu deleteMenu;

   public JMenu buildMenus(List<SomeObject> objsThatGoInMenu) {
      openMenu = new JMenu("Open");
      deleteMenu = new JMenu("Delete");

      for( SomeObject so : objsThatGoInMenu ) {
         addMenuOptions( so );
      }

      JMenu father = new JMenu("Father");
      father.add( openMenu );
      father.add( deleteMenu );
   }

public addMenuOptions( final SomeObject so ) {
   final JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem( new AbstractAction( so.getName() ) {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         // todo open
      }
   }));
   final JMenuItem deleteMenuItem = new JMenuItem( new AbstractAction( so.getName() ) {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         deleteMenu.remove( deleteMenuItem );
         openMenu.remove( openMenuItem );
      }
   }));

   openMenu.add( openMenuItem );
   deleteMenu.add( deleteMenuItem );
 }
 }
```

Comment: believe me, if things were as easy as keeping a pointer to openItems i would've never gone through all the trouble.

Comment: Well why don't you explain why that wouldn't work?  Your code is 90% walking the hierarchy and 10% actually doing something.  As far as I can tell it just removes the corresponding menu item to what's in the delete menu.

Comment: yes well. that's what i wanted to do. sadly didn't have a pointer to items, so that's why i had to go such a long way.